# Syntax to refer to a template (alias?)

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

I'm working on porting some Julia code to C++ and have run into a problem. To make matters worse I'm not very familiar with the C++ nomenclature, so haven't been able to google my way out.

Basically, I'm trying to figure out how to refer to a template (is this a template alias?) so I can use it later, i.e., to refer to a type. I've tried various incantations involving `using`, `typename`, and `template`, but nothing seems to make my compiler happy. I have managed to produce something which does what I want (see below), but it is pretty nasty. Is there a better way? Any reasonable C++ is fine.

The following code is a minimal example of what I'm trying to achieve

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template<int n, template<int> class T>
int unwrap(T<n>& x) { return n; }

template<int n>
struct A { static const char name = 'A'; };

template<int n>
struct B { static const char name = 'B'; };

template<bool flag>
struct promote_if {
    template<int n> using type = A<n>;
};

template<> 
struct promote_if<true> {
    template<int n> using type = B<n>;
};

template<int m, int n, 
template<int> class X, 
template<int> class Y, 
template<int> class Z>
struct Stuff { static const int seven = 7; };

// Add type parameters and return 
// B<m + n> if X or Y is a B,
// otherwise return A<m + n>
template<int m, int n, template<int> class X, template<int> class Y> 
auto add(X<m>& x, Y<n>& y) {
    static const bool any = std::is_base_of<B<m>, X<m>>::value || std::is_base_of<B<n>, Y<n>>::value;
    // This works, but is gross
    std::cout << Stuff<m,n,promote_if<any>::template type,X,Y>::seven << "\n";
    typename promote_if<any>::template type<m + n> z;

    // Something like this is what I'm trying to achieve
    // using T = typename promote_if<any>::template type;
    // T<m + n> z;
    // std::cout << Stuff<m,n,T,X,Y>::seven << "\n";
    return z;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    A<1> a;
    B<2> b;
    auto c = add(a, a);
    std::cout << "c = add(a, a) = " << c.name << "<" << unwrap(c) << ">\n";

    auto d = add(a, b);
    std::cout << "d = add(a, b) = " << d.name << "<" << unwrap(d) << ">\n";
    return 0;
}
// Output
// Stuff is 7
// c = add(a, a) = A<2>
// Stuff is 7
// d = add(a, b) = B<3>
```

Comment: [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: The best way to ask "Is there a better way?" would be to explain, in plain English, what you are trying to accomplish here. Otherwise what you are essentially asking for is somewhere to reverse-engineer your existing code, figure out what it's trying to accomplish, and only ***then*** try to figure out a better approach. You can save quite a bit of time by making the first two steps unnecessary.

Comment: All this `template<int n>` is extremely unusual in other C++ code. What are you trying to do with that?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Thanks for the feedback. The above is my best attempt to do just that. This code is not what I'm working on, it is just a minimal working example that demonstrates what I'm trying to achieve. I've pointed out what works, and what I'm hoping to achieve. I'm just hoping someone with better C++ chops than I could help with the syntax to accomplish it.

Comment: @BoPersson The types I'm working with in my project are Tensors. I'm using int template parameters in my own code to a.) dispatch correctly for broadcasting operations (add a m x 1 column vector to a m x n matrix), and b.) enable compile time dimension checks. All that is quite tangential to the question though, for the purposes of the example they could have just as easily used a type.

Comment: If the "above is my best attempt to do just that", then we must be speaking different English languages. That doesn't look like an explanation, in any plain English that I know.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Sorry about that. Perhaps the problem is that I couldn't find a clear way to explain my intent, outside of "Basically, I'm trying to figure out how to refer to a template (is this a template alias?) so I can use it later, i.e., to refer to a type." To compensate I mocked up a minimal working example with comments marking exactly the areas I was struggling. If you have suggestions for how to help clarify, I'm all ears.

Comment: "How to refer to a template" is faulty terminology. When working with templates, you refer to template ***parameters*** . In order to determine whether a template parameter is itself a template, or something else, using template specialization would be a typical approach. Or an SFINAE-based approach. There is no universal answer here that will apply to every situation. It depends on each use case.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I imagine my incorrect terminology is a huge problem. Are you aware of the correct terminology to describe the case I'm interested in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
template<int m, int n, template<int> class X, template<int> class Y> 
auto add(X<m>& x, Y<n>& y) {
    static const bool any = std::is_base_of<B<m>, X<m>>::value || std::is_base_of<B<n>, Y<n>>::value;
    // This works, but is gross
    std::cout << Stuff<m,n,promote_if<any>::template type,X,Y>::seven << "\n";
    typename promote_if<any>::template type<m + n> z;

    // Something like this is what I'm trying to achieve
    // using T = typename promote_if<any>::template type;
    // T<m + n> z;
    // std::cout << Stuff<m,n,T,X,Y>::seven << "\n";
    return z;
}
```

try

```
// Add type parameters and return 
// B<m + n> if X or Y is a B,
// otherwise return A<m + n>
template<int m, int n, template<int> class X, template<int> class Y> 
auto add(X<m>& x, Y<n>& y) {
    static const bool any = std::is_base_of<B<m>, X<m>>::value || std::is_base_of<B<n>, Y<n>>::value;

    using T = promote_if<any>;
    typename T::template type<m + n> z;
    std::cout << Stuff<m,n,T::template type,X,Y>::seven << "\n";
    return z;
}
```

I just tried some combinations of `typename` and `template` and so on and let the g++ compiler's diagnostics steer me towards working code.

I think this is still ugly, though.

A probably better solution would be to rethink the whole thing and change the design.